# Bilinear and linear map, then zero map

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

If $b:V\times V\rightarrow W$ is both bilinear and linear, then it is the zero map. How do I prove this?

What I tried:

> linear: $b((x,y)+(x',y'))=b(x,y)+b(x',y')$ and
>   bilinear:$b((x,y)+(x',y'))=b(x,y)+b(x',y)+b(x,y')+b(x',y')$.

How do I continue from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can derive from $b$ being bilinear that for all $x, y \in V$
$$
b(x, 0) = b(0, y) = 0.
$$
This is true, since every linear map maps $0$ to $0$.
Together with linearity it follows that
$$
b(x,y) = b(x, 0) + b(0, y) = 0
$$